# Is Umbraco suitable for a LOB application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, plugins, mef, umbraco, lob

I wonder if Umbraco 5, which is based on MVC, is appropriate for a Line of Business application, mainly to handle extensibility.

Would it be a good ideia to use Umbraco as a base, and create modules to be installed on it?

Does Umbraco use MEF for extensibility, or something similar?

Note: I don't have any experience with Umbraco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you properly know umbraco 5 is only in beta mode atm..

but umbraco 5 looks really promising, you can read some of umbraco thoughts about MEF [here](http://umbraco.com/follow-us/blog-archive/2010/12/1/thoughts-on-plugins-with-umbraco-5.aspx)